# How can I SUMIF where the IF evaluates whether a date is between two dates?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**UPDATE**: The contents of Column K were not, in fact, formatted as numbers all the way through.

Given:

> Column F_____Column K_____Column M
>
> 3/1/2015_____1____________2/1/2015
>
> 2/1/2015_____2____________3/1/2015
>
> 2/1/2015_____3____________4/1/2015

where columns F and M are formatted as dates and K as numbers. Column F is not sorted, Column M is. Every date is for the 1st of its month.

I want to populate Column N such that each row sums the elements in column K whose corresponding value in Column F is in the month of Column M.

Tried:

> SUMIF($F$2:$F$12500, AND(">="&M2, "<"&M3), $K$2:$K$12500)

Get zeroes across the board. Evaluating whether row 2 Column M and row 1 Column F are equal yields TRUE. What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the assumption that all dates are the first of the month you don't have to restrict it to being in between the 2 dates on `F:F` but just rather that the dates has to match `M2`. With that in mind you can simply do the following:

```
N2 = SUMIF(F:F,M2,K:K)
```

This will add all the values in `K:K` for rows that have the same month (hence exact same date) as `M2`. Hope I interpreted your question correctly. Regards.

Comment: That works–thank you. I'm using the AND because I also want to create an annual summary, for which I'd need e.g. the sum of values which occurred between 1 January 2014 and 1 January 2015. Still running into zeroes for that.

Comment: Then you would use `SUMIFS` and place each date in a separate constraint. You can apply more than 1 constraint to the same column in `SUMIFS` and it will consider only rows where all constraints are met. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you. Any clue why the AND approach fails?

Comment: I think it's because Excel processes the `AND` before then trying to apply that logic to an array. That will always error out because `">="&M2` is not a logical construct (it wont answer true or false). It's just not the way that `SUMIF` was scripted. If you have more than 1 constraint you have to use `SUMIFS`. Cheers